# iOS merging of two disjoint UIBezierPaths, minimum uibezierpath that encloses both

Tags: ios, merge, uibezierpath, cgpath

I have two UIBezierPath objects, e.g. `starPath` and `hexaPath`. I want to create a merged path with single enclosure as shown in the dotted path in the diagram.

But following code results in two enclosed individual paths.

```
UIBezierPath * resultPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[resultPath appendPath:starPath];
[resultPath appendPath:hexaPath];
```

I want the dotted path shown in the diagram. Please help.
[image: Merged path wanted]

Comment: But you don't actually know the closest points between the 2 different paths, or specifically where each starts and ends. It also isn't easy to deconstruct the paths to determine these points. Where are the original paths coming from?

Comment: Wain, thats exactly where I am lost. How do we convert multiple closed loops in a uibezierpath to a single closed loop? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Are the paths all straight lines, or do they include arcs?

Comment: They include arcs and have irregular shapes, but closed paths.

Comment: This is a hard problem. I would suggest that you ignore the raw paths and instead look at doing edge detection image processing.